# Slow down animation in css3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, animation

I would like to ask how to properly slow down animation in css, im making my portfolio and cant get it working..

I want to show my photo first and after that animation is done, show the welcome text, it's appearing at the same time at the moment.

I'm using unedited animate.css(can't paste it here because its too long, and im limited to 30k characters)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Portfolio - Martin Mičulka</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Loading Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/vendor/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="animate.css" rel="stylesheet"> 

    <!-- Loading Flat UI -->
    <link href="css/flat-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico">
    <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements. All other JS at the end of file. -->
      <script src="js/vendor/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="js/vendor/respond.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
  <header>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
       <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-01">
       <span class="sr-only">Navigace</span>
       </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">martin mičulka</a>
      </div><!--navbar-header-->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-01" id="navbar">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#home" data-loc="home">domů</a></li>
                <li><a href="#ome" data-loc="ome">o mě</a></li>
                <li><a href="#galerie" data-loc="galerie">galerie</a></li>
                <li><a href="#kontakt" data-loc="kontakt">kontakt</a></li>
              </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
</header>

<section id="home" class="scroll-panel">
  <div class="jumbotron" id="modry">
    <div class="container">
      <center>
       <img src="img/fotka.jpg" class="img-circle animated bounceInDown" width="200px" height="200px" id="fotka" >
        <div class="col-md-12">
         <div class="row">
           <p class="lead animated flipInX" id="welcome">Vítejte na mém portfoliu, zde budu uveřejňovat svoje dosavadní práce</p>
         </div><!--row-->
        </div><!--col-md-12-->
      </center><!--center-->
    </div><!--container-->
  </div><!--jumbotron-->
</section>




    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Flat UI's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="js/vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/vendor/video.js"></script>
    <script src="js/flat-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.scrollTo.js"></script>   
       <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
  $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      var target = this.hash;
      $target = $(target);

      $('html, body').stop().animate({
          'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
      }, 900, 'swing', function () {
          window.location.hash = target;
      });
  });
});

       </script>
  </body>
</html>

.animated.flip {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
          backface-visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation-name: flip;
          animation-name: flip;
}

@-webkit-keyframes flipInX {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
            transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
            transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  40% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -20deg);
            transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -20deg);
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
            transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  }

  60% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 10deg);
            transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 10deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }

  80% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -5deg);
            transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -5deg);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px);
            transform: perspective(400px);
  }
}

@keyframes flipInX {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
            transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
            transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  40% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -20deg);
            transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -20deg);
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
            transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  }

  60% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 10deg);
            transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 10deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }

  80% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -5deg);
            transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -5deg);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px);
            transform: perspective(400px);
  }
}

.flipInX {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible !important;
          backface-visibility: visible !important;
  -webkit-animation-name: flipInX;
          animation-name: flipInX;
}

.bounceIn {
  -webkit-animation-name: bounceIn;
          animation-name: bounceIn;
  -webkit-animation-duration: .75s;
          animation-duration: .75s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounceInDown {
  0%, 60%, 75%, 90%, 100% {
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
            transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
  }

  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -3000px, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, -3000px, 0);
  }

  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 25px, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 25px, 0);
  }

  75% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0);
  }

  90% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 5px, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 5px, 0);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: none;
            transform: none;
  }
}

@keyframes bounceInDown {
  0%, 60%, 75%, 90%, 100% {
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
            transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
  }

  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -3000px, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, -3000px, 0);
  }

  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 25px, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 25px, 0);
  }

  75% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0);
  }

  90% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 5px, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 5px, 0);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: none;
            transform: none;
  }
}

.bounceInDown {
  -webkit-animation-name: bounceInDown;
          animation-name: bounceInDown;
}
```

This is my HTML of my website, im using bounceInDown and flipInX animations.

Thanks for the help ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could detect the end of the first animation and then call the second one in another function.

```
$('#yourElement').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', doSomething);
```

There are also some examples here:  http://davidwalsh.name/css-animation-callback